# Limited context in OpenAI prompt with embeddings

Tags: nlp, openai-api, word-embedding, chatgpt-api, pinecone

I am playing around with OpenAI and 10k SEC PDF filings. My stack is OpenAI + Langchain + Pinecone.

I am trying to ask a simple question which is "What was AAPL's revenue in 2022" by using embeddings and feeding the context from Pinecone in the prompt.

If I have only 1 PDF file in the index, everything works fine and the answer is correct. Once I feed in multiple documents of several years, say 5 (2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022), I basically never get the right answer as the pinecone query returns wrong context (typically from years say 2018 and 2019 or 2021).

How would you go about that? If my idea is to feed it with 5000 filings, is the embedding technique the right way to go or maybe fine tuning a model is a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Finetuning a foundation model is way harder compared to adding some context to your prompt, so I would not take that road.

I am making the assumption that the chunks of text that you are feeding into Pinecone do not contain the actual year because it would be kind of stupid to repeat it many times in a financial report. That is why the correct chunk can not be picked from the Pinecone database.

If your typical use case is questioning a financial report, you could add the year as metadata to Pinecone. If now a question is asked about 2022, only use text chunks that have the metadata field year set to 2022.